# ggplot histogram with labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to label to different histograms that are in the same plot. By labels, I want to identify by colors each histogram, for example one green that corresponds to x and one red that corresponds to y.

I tried to use the function label. But it is not working.

[image]

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data=junk, aes(x),fill="green", alpha=.2) +
  geom_histogram(data=jun, aes(y), fill="red", alpha=.2)+
  labs(x = "something") + 
  ggtitle("title")
```

I expect to have both histograms, one green and the other one red, and labels in the right describing each histogram.

Answer (score 0):

for this, you need to have the data in long format, so the data that should make up the green histogram and the data that make up the red one in a data frame below one another, and another column, that defines the groups.

```r
df=data.frame(values=rnorm(20000),colorby=c("red_values","green_values"))

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=values,fill=colorby))+
  geom_histogram(position="dodge")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red_values"="red","green_values"="green"))
```

For the position argument you could also try if `"stack"` fits your needs better.

[image: with position <code>"stack"</code>]

[image: with position <code>"dodge"</code>]